# MS Office 2013 and Asian languages

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, keyboard, language

I've got a Win7 computer with Office 2013 installed. System language is German.

When switching input language to Thai I can type in the system dialog boxes (like start buttno app finder), but can't type in MS Word (pressing the keys on the keyboard does nothing on the screen, the cursor doesn't move). The weirdest thing here is: if I use numeric keypad and type any number after that the keyboard starts working in Word for a few characters.

Japanese and Nepal input languages work fine.

Does anyone know any way to troubleshoot?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have all the required Office 2013 language packs installed?

Comment: No, because I don't need anything of their functionality (IME, proofing, etc)

Comment: I highly suspect yourr problem is caused by the lack of those language packs.